# How to replace text in a range of UITextView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have textview and when a user types a link it's color should be changed. I tried with the following,

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *stringWithNSDataDetector = [textView text];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDataDetector * dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                                                                    error:&error];
        UIFont *fontNormal = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Light" size:18.0];
        __block NSMutableArray *allMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [dataDetector enumerateMatchesInString:stringWithNSDataDetector
                                   options:0
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringWithNSDataDetector length])
                                usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
         {
             if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink){
                 [allMatches addObject:[match URL]];
                 NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString =   [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[[match URL] absoluteString]attributes:nil];
                 NSRange rangeOfUrl = NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString string].length);
                 [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontNormal range:rangeOfUrl];
                 [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorFromHexString:TEXT_FIELD_UNDERLINE_BLUE] range:rangeOfUrl];

                 NSMutableAttributedString *finalizedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.postTxtView.text];

                 [finalizedStr replaceCharactersInRange:rangeOfUrl withAttributedString:attributedString];
                 self.postTxtView.attributedText = finalizedStr;
             }
         }];

        for (NSURL *url in allMatches) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [url absoluteString]);
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This one is working for finding links well. But once the link is found and press the space button, only that link should be coloured.

**Before I pressed the  space**
[image]

**After I press the space**
[image]

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the replacement yourself, you should return NO so that the caller does not also do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
NSRange rangeOfUrl = NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString string].length);
NSMutableAttributedString *finalizedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.postTxtView.text];
[finalizedStr replaceCharactersInRange:rangeOfUrl withAttributedString:attributedString];
self.postTxtView.attributedText = finalizedStr;
```

So the first line starts with a range whose `location` is *zero* - that is, *the start* of the string. You are then inserting your attributed string at that range - that is, at *the start* of the string. You are then replacing the whole text view text with that, so the colored URL appears at *the start* of the text.

Comment: To make this working, I need to hold the url range in a variable and replacing the text with that range. right?

Comment: Did you read what I said? The `0` is wrong. You are looking at the URL represented by `match` but you are not looking at where in your overall string `match` _is_.